# How do I separate posted values from a form in PHP

Tags: php

how pass multiple values to paypal. I used it in paypal submission page

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="id_cart={$id_cart}&option={option}" />
```

I get

```
$_POST['custom'] = id_cart=534&option=1620850004 ,
```

how I get it separately like

```
 $_POST['id_cart'] =534 , $_POST['option'] =1620850004.
```

Comment: If an error occurs, please post the **error** instead of just the failing code.

Comment: please give me a solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name attribute on your form fields will become the key server-side, simply break your current hidden field up with new names:

You should also be escaping the values on the page, I'm assuming you're using smarty...

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_cart" value="{$id_cart|htmspecialchars}" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="{$option|htmspecialchars}" />
```

If you want / need to keep your HTML the same, you can split the values on the server-side with parse_str:

```
$r = array();
parse_str($_POST['custom'], $r);

print $r['id_cart'];
print $r['option'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those values are stored in $id_cart and $option AND you really want a querystring-like parameter in your hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="custom={$id_cart}&option={$option}" />
```

Comment: can you see your page when you not enter any value in hidden field?

Comment: ya i can see the page, but i put this code then the page is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this way

```
{php}
$value = 'custom='.{$id_cart}.'&option='.{$option}
{/php}
```

use this "$value" into your hidden box

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the hidden control's name...?
because the value which posted like "custom=" and the name is also have "custom"

so there may be some conjunctions..please change that and let ma know.

Comment: Prabhu: i changed it , but i get $_POST['custom'] = id_cart=534&option=1620850004 , how i get it seperately like $_POST['id_cart'] =534  , $_POST['option'] =1620850004.